# GCloud SDK Versioned Archives How to Solve Install.bat error "Please verify that the following is the path to a working Python 2.7 executable"

Tags: gcloud

Trying to install GCloud SDK on windows 7 professional ....

I have installed successfully and correctly Python 2.7.15 on "G:\Python27"

I have reset the computer

I have downloaded google-cloud-sdk-223.0.0-windows-x86_64.zip and unzip it to "G:\GCloudSDK223" (from https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-versioned-archives)

I have done this because the interactive installer keeps generating a similar error because I am behind a firewall/proxy/whatever.

The workaround is to install the versioned archives.

When running install.bat I get the following error :

---

```
G:\GCloudSDK223>install.bat
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
ERROR: gcloud failed to load: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases ordereddict, CommentedBase, MutableMapping
    gcloud_main = _import_gcloud_main()
    import googlecloudsdk.gcloud_main
    from googlecloudsdk.calliope import base
    from googlecloudsdk.calliope import display
    from googlecloudsdk.core.resource import resource_printer
    from googlecloudsdk.core.resource import yaml_printer
    from googlecloudsdk.core.yaml import dict_like
    from googlecloudsdk.core import yaml_location_value
    from ruamel import yaml
    from ruamel.yaml.main import *  # NOQA
    from ruamel.yaml.loader import BaseLoader, SafeLoader, Loader, RoundTripLoader  # NOQA
    from ruamel.yaml.constructor import (
    from ruamel.yaml.comments import *                               # NOQA
    class CommentedMap(MutableMapping, ordereddict, CommentedBase):
    cls = super(ABCMeta, mcls).__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace)
    Cannot create a consistent method resolution

This usually indicates corruption in your gcloud installation or problems with your Python interpreter.

Please verify that the following is the path to a working Python 2.7 executable:
    G:\Python27\python.exe

If it is not, please set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to a working Python 2.7 executable.

If you are still experiencing problems, please reinstall the Cloud SDK using the instructions here:
    https://cloud.google.com/sdk/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\GCloudSDK223\\bin\bootstrapping\install.py", line 12, in <module>
    import bootstrapping
  File "G:\GCloudSDK223\bin\bootstrapping\bootstrapping.py", line 44, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.credentials import store as c_store
  File "G:\GCloudSDK223\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\credentials\store.py", line 35, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.credentials import creds
  File "G:\GCloudSDK223\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\credentials\creds.py", line 42, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "C:\Program Files\CollabNet Subversion Edge\Python25\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "C:\Program Files\CollabNet Subversion Edge\Python25\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3

G:\GCloudSDK223>
```

---

What must I do ? Any clues at least ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while trying to install google-cloud-sdk version 227.

I also had to set the `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` environment variable, after doing so, the install script and all `gcloud` commands still failed with the same error you posted.

the included version of the library referenced in your stack trace `ruamel.yaml` is 0.15.74. Looking at the project page for `ruamel.yaml` shows that they fixed a bug relating to this issue a few days ago (2018-12-06) in version 0.15.81

https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml/

I can't be 100% certain that's the cause, but I removed the included version by deleting the directory `google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/ruamel`, installed the newest version in my local environment by running `pip install ruamel.yaml`, and now everything works.

If you're not willing to perform that sort of surgery (understandable) then you'll have to wait for google to update that library in the sdk. I opened a bug report just now:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120715430

Answer (score 0):

You might simply have a corrupted download. You should try to rather install the "Windows 64-bit(x86_64) with Python bundled" file from the versioned archives page, to avoid issues related to paths to Python installation.

Installing Cloud SDK behind a corporate proxy requires a few extra steps. Once you have the SDK installed properly, proxy settings can be configured via Cloud SDK properties by using the typical gcloud config mechanism. Details are provided in the "Proxy configuration" sub-chapter of the "Configuring Cloud SDK for use behind a proxy/firewall" documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/proxy-settings#proxy_configuration). 
This page shows you how to use the "gcloud config set proxy/" command to configure your installation to work with the corporate proxy.

Comment: Thanks Mr. @George.

Comment: Thanks Mr. @George. First, I dont think Google's gonna host corrupted files, I downloaded several times, compare files and were equals, besides I compared the SHA256. Second I tried the version you suggested (python bundled) (checking the files as before) and I get the same results, only indicating that python is under subfolder "...\platform\bundledpython\python.exe" and that is not a working exe, but if I run the python under this folder, it runs and opens without errors or problems. We also tried deactivating proxy with same results. So I am still the same as when I asked the question.

Comment: @Pregunton Files might get corrupted during download, but you have made sure this is not the case. How are your new results indicating that python.exe is not a working executable? The exact copy of the install messages would come handy here, and of the error text.
How did you disable proxy? To avoid any proxy interference, you should attempt the same Cloud SDK in another location, where no proxy is installed.

Comment: Thanks again.Now I succesfully installed GCloudSDK I dont have exact error message after trying python bundled version, it was pretty much the same "Please verify that the following is the path to a working Python 2.7 executable: ... " (I know u want the whole message). About disabling proxy it was someone from infrastructure that help me, but the important thing is that when I mentioned proxy as part of the problem, in my case it was a supposition because some information I read, but like I said I got to successfully installed and proxy is not a variable. Pls c my answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of try and error, found that the system environment PYTHONHOME must be the path to the last version of python that you installed or the version that you want to use and it is installed properly. It seems obvious, but for some reason I had 
PYTHONHOME=C:\Program Files\CollabNet Subversion Edge\Python25\ 
(Though this is a working version too).

Now I have python properly installed on "G:\Python27" so

PYTHONHOME=G:\Python27\

must be the value to configure on Windows itself (not on any bat file or something).

I also added the line 
"SET CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=G:\Python27\python.exe" before the line 
"IF "%CLOUDSDK_PYTHON%"=="" ("

on the "install.bat".

Finally open a command line with Administrative Rights AFTER changing the value of PYTHONHOME to execute the "install.bat" file.

At least to my case this is the solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if the .bat file is significantly different, but in the .sh script, the value of `PYTHONHOME` is actually unset in all cases.

It's possible that what you did caused the environment to point to a working version of the `ruamel.yaml` python module, but it looks like that library actually has a bug that's causing this issue. I had to install a newer version of it even after settng `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON`, see my answer for more details.